# C++: handle sql-String in UTF32

Tags: c++, mysql, unicode, utf

I'm writing a program, that reads a UTF32 encoded string from a MySQL-Database and should write it to a file/cout. The Problem is, that as long as I just use letters and so on, it works, but as soon as I take a emojicon it just writes a "?". I tried:
1. Change the locale (with `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_EN.UTF-32");`) 
2. Use `wstrings`but gives an eror like that: Can't convert sql::String to wstring...

Any suggestions how to do this?

I use the following (shortened) code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;         
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect(IP, USER, Password);
        con->setSchema(DBNAME);
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res= stmt->executeQuery("Select * from messages");         
        std::string tmp;
        while (res->next()) {
              tmp = res->getString(7);
              std::cout << tmp;
        }
}
```

The MySQL-Field is created with the following (shortened) command:

```
std::string msgs = "CREATE TABLE if not Exists `"+dbnam+e"`.`messages` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `message` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_bin NOT NULL ,
    UNIQUE (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;;
stmt->execute(msgs);"
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: On which platform? Does your terminal support emojis?

Comment: Let's see the hex for the emoji in question.

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's Debian 10. Yes, the terminal supports emojis.

Comment: @RickJames I edited the question to add the statement, its for example the smiling face emoji(but none of those which I tested works...

Comment: From within the C++ code, print the hex of an emoji that you are about to `INSERT` into `messages`.